# What product of cyclic groups is isomorphic to $U_{57}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to find a product of cyclic groups which is isomorphic to the group $U_{57}$. I know that

$U_{57} = \{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 37, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 52, 53, 55, 56\}.$

The order of $U_{57}$ is $36 = 6^2$.

I know that there is a theorem that says that if $G$ is an abelian group with order $p^n$, with $p$ being prime then $G$ is a product of cyclic groups, however, I don't necessarily know if $U_{57}$ is abelian so I can't use that theorem here.
Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Factor $57$ and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. ($U_{57}$ is *absolutely* abelian! The product is just the integer product modulo $57$; does multiplication of integers commute?)

Comment: Note: $6$ is not a prime so the theorem you mentioned is not applicable. Also $U_n$ is abelian for all $n$ (just use the definition of modular multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

$G=U_{57}$ is isomorphic to the direct product of two abelian groups of orders $4$ and $9.$ Since there are
at least two elements of order $2$ in $G,$ the first factor must be $\Bbb{Z}_2\times \Bbb{Z}_2.$
The second factor is
$\Bbb{Z}_9$ because $G$ contains an element of order $9.$ The isomorphism $\varphi$ from
$\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_9$ to $G$ is
$$\varphi(x,y,z)=(-1)^x20^y4^z\pmod{57}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(\mathbb Z/57)^\times\cong (\mathbb Z/3\times\mathbb Z/19)^\times\cong(\mathbb Z/3)^\times\times(\mathbb Z/19)^\times\cong\mathbb Z/2\times\mathbb Z/18$.